# How can I add a preprocessing task in gradle

Tags: gradle

I want to instrument my sourcecode files with openclover during normal compilation, because I want to use it in a server enviroment.
The idea is to run our selenium tests against the instrumented source code and get a code coverage this way. Also this could be used to replay standard usage scenarios and find hotspots for optimization.
For that the standard build needs to instrument the source code files.

I created a build.gradle similar to the one shown [here](http://openclover.org/doc/manual/4.2.0/gradle--gradle-clover-plugin.html).

Snippet:

```
sourceSets {
   clover {
       java {
          srcDir "$buildDir/sources-instr"
      }
   }
}
task cloverInstr() {
  inputs.files sourceSets.main.allJava
  outputs.dir "$buildDir/sources-instr"

  doFirst {
      [...]

    com.atlassian.clover.CloverInstr.mainImpl(args)
    }
}

cloverClasses.dependsOn cloverInstr

test {
  def cloverClasspath = configurations.testRuntime + configurations.cloverRuntime + sourceSets.test.output + sourceSets.clover.output
  classpath = cloverClasspath
}
```

This one changes the test task to use the classes from the clover source set instead of the classes from the main source set. I would like to preprocess the classes in the main source set however.

So my idea is: `main: instrument -> compile -> jar`, whilst the shown solution is using two source sets:

```
main: compile -> jar
clover: instrument -> compile -> test
```

What would be the best way to instrument the source files with clover and pass them into compilation? Ideally I would even have a switch which enables instrumentation or disables it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the source sets works. When using `-PwithClover` the following section is activated. It changes the main source set to the path where the instrumented code will be. Then the compile task gets a dependency which instruments the code to the same path.

Its a bit hacky, but it works.

```
if (project.hasProperty("withClover")) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }

            dependencies {
                classpath 'org.openclover:clover:4.3.1'
            }
        }

        configurations {
            cloverRuntime
            cloverRuntime.extendsFrom cloverCompile
        }
        //swap src dirs, main is now the instrumented and clover the actual srcs
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java {
                    srcDirs = ["$buildDir/sources-instr"]
                }
            }
            clover {
                java {
                    srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            //compile 'org.openclover:clover:4.3.1'
            // make sure clover is available in the jar
            embed 'org.openclover:clover:4.3.1'
        }
        //instrumentation task
        task cloverInstr() {
            inputs.files sourceSets.clover.allJava
            outputs.dir "${buildDir}/sources-instr"
            doFirst {
                def argsList = ["--initstring", "${buildDir}/clover/clover.db",
                                "-d", "${buildDir}/sources-instr"]
                argsList.addAll(inputs.files.files.collect({ file ->
                    file.absolutePath
                }))
                String[] args = argsList.toArray()
                com.atlassian.clover.CloverInstr.mainImpl(args)
            }
        }
        //create src files for main src set
        compileJava.dependsOn "cloverInstr"
    }
```